# DateTime formatting in Ruby on Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, datetime

I need to add this to my RoR 4 app to set default time, date and datetime formats. 
I followed this guide but I wasn't able to get it to work.
I added it to the application.rb but dates would only change from 2014-05-27 07:05:00 UTC to 27/May/2014, and I want it to be 27/05/2014 5:00 PM.

http://blog.nicoschuele.com/posts/cheatsheet-to-set-app-wide-date-and-time-formats-in-rails

```
  # Date
  # ----------------------------
  Date::DATE_FORMATS[:default] = "%e/%B/%Y" 

  # DateTime
  # ----------------------------
  DateTime::DATE_FORMATS[:default] = "%m/%d/%Y %I:%M %p" 
  # Time
  # ----------------------------
  Time::DATE_FORMATS[:default] = "%e/%B/%Y"
```

Comment: have you restarted your app?

Comment: This the manual way = @accident.date.strftime("%m/%d/%Y %I:%M %p")

Comment: so you want `27/05/2014 5:00 PM.`? are you using `Date` or `DateTime`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I'm not sure why the article that you linked to differentiates between `DateTime::DATE_FORMATS` and `Time::DATE_FORMATS`. In my experience (and, apparently, in yours as well) `Time::DATE_FORMATS` speaks for *Time* as well as for *Date* objects. So do this instead:

```
# Date
# ----------------------------
Date::DATE_FORMATS[:default] = "%e/%B/%Y" 

# DateTime / Time
# ----------------------------
Time::DATE_FORMATS[:default] = "%m/%d/%Y %I:%M %p"
```

Here is example output from this in my console:

```
> DateTime.current.to_s # => "05/27/2014 01:19 AM"
> Time.current.to_s     # => "05/27/2014 01:19 AM"
> Date.current.to_s     # => "27/May/2014"
```

Answer (score 6):

You should use the `I18n` helpers in combination with locales settings

```
I18n.localize(your_datetime_column, format: :short)
```

Then specify the formats in the locals file, i.e. `config/locales/en.yml`, you can modify the existing short and long or add your own format keys. You might need to restart rails after changing the locales files.

see also: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#adding-date-time-formats

Answer (score 4):

Without going through what the tutorial suggested, you can simply create a helper method and put it in your `Helper` folder. call that helper method in your views. Here is an example.

use the [strftime](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/date/rdoc/DateTime.html#method-i-strftime) method.

```
def date_format(date)
   date.strftime("%d/%m/%Y %I:%M %p")
end
```

I tested it in `irb`.

```
>> require 'date'
=> true
>> d = DateTime.now
=> #<DateTime: 2014-05-26T18:54:59-05:00 ((2456804j,86099s,806097708n),-18000s,2299161j)>
>> def date_format(date)
>> date.strftime("%d/%m/%Y %I:%M %p")
>> end
=> nil
>> date_format(d)
=> "26/05/2014 06:54 PM"
>>
```

Comment: The answers above use wrappers around strftime I don’t see this as any issue at all. In fact this answer is targeted at pure ruby. I think its best to understand the language + the framework

Comment: This is called perfect answer.